# Как правильно подключиться к СУБД PostreSQL на удаленном сервере?

Tags: postgresql

Есть удаленный инстанс ORACLE с доступом по ssh. Развернул там postgresql. Настроил postgresql.conf на прослушивание всех подключений и в pg_hba.conf добавил строку host all all 0.0.0.0/ trust чтобы можно было подключиться без пароля, потому что для стокового пользователя postgres я его не знаю, а нового пользователя не создавал. После пытался подключиться напрямую и через ssh tunnel (используя ключ по которому подключаюсь к серверу по ssh) через утилиту pgAdmin. Ничего не вышло. pgAdmin при прямом подключении говорит, что таймаут превышен, а через ssh просто не может установить. Может кто сталкивался с таким? Вроде как распространенная методика подключения к удаленной СУБД.

P.S. В основном пользовался инструкцией отсюда: https://mhelp.pro/ru/kak-nastroit-udalennoye-podklyucheniye-k-bd-postgresql-iz-windows/

Comment: После правки в pg_hba рестартили бд?

Comment: Да, конечно, командой /etc/init.d/postgresql restart. И такой командой systemctl restart postgresql